# Where are my QFieldCloud files stored on an iPad?

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I'm trying to sync data from a geopackage on QField from my mobile device (in this case an iPad 2) back on to my main machine, a Macbook. For some reason, when I push changes to the cloud, and synchronize on my machine, the updated layers are not appearing even though they are there on the iPad.

Where can I get the local files from on the iPad, so I can just copy them over? They're not in the QField folders when I connect to USB.